# 5 Year Visit visa while 2 year visit visa has 10 months?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, uk-visa, uk-visitor-visa

My parents visit visa to uk for 2 years has still 10 months left in it. Can i apply for 5 year visit visa right now. As in future our financial scenario will be changing.

Comment: The earliest you can apply for a visit visa is 3 months before the intended travel date. What rationale would you give to UKVI to justify effectively cancelling a 2 year visa that is not much more than half way through its validity period, when a visit could be made using their existing visa?